# Extracting the slope for individual observation

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R. I have a data set with 3 set of lung function measurements for 3 corresponding dates given below for each observation. I would like to extract slope for each observation(decline in lung function) using R software  and insert in the new column for each observation.
1. How should I approach the problem?
2. Is my data set arranged in right format?

```
ID      FEV1_Date11 FEV1_Date12 FEV1_Date13  DATE11     DATE12     DATE13
18105   1.35        1.25        1.04         6/9/1990   8/16/1991  8/27/1993
18200   0.87        0.85                     9/12/1991  3/11/1993   
18303   0.79                                 4/23/1992      
24204   4.05        3.95        3.99         6/8/1992   3/22/1993  11/5/1994
28102   1.19        1.04        0.96         10/31/1990 7/24/1991  6/27/1992
34104   1.03        1.16        1.15         7/25/1992  12/8/1993  12/7/1994
43108   0.92        0.83        0.79         6/23/1993  1/12/1994  1/11/1995
103114  2.43        2.28        2.16         6/5/1994   6/21/1995  4/7/1996
114101  0.73        0.59        0.6          6/25/1989  8/5/1990   8/24/1991
```

example for 1st observation, slope=0.0003
[image]
Thanks..

Comment: please `dput()` an extract of your data or give its`str()`.

Comment: You'll first want to decide how exactly you want to plot your data, and how you want the slope to be calculated. Your dataset looks fine as-is, but it's more important to see how the data is stored in your copy of R.

Comment: @tluh. x axis will have dates and Y axis will have FEV1_1. I was able to plot it in excel by scatterplot function a

Comment: When I run your first data point through `lm` I get `-3.078e-09` as the slope.  Perhaps I am missing something. Are you sure Excel is handling the dates correctly ?

Comment: Both answers give different results, which gives you what you are asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question, I think you want the slope between each set of visits:

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("DATE")), funs(as.Date(., "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>% 
  do(data_frame(slope=diff(unlist(.[,2:4]))/diff(unlist(.[,5:7])),
                after_visit=1+(1:length(slope))))

## Source: local data frame [18 x 3]
## Groups: ID [9]
## 
##        ID         slope after_visit
##     <int>         <dbl>       <dbl>
## 1   18105 -2.309469e-04           2
## 2   18105 -2.830189e-04           3
## 3   18200 -3.663004e-05           2
## 4   18200            NA           3
## 5   18303            NA           2
## 6   18303            NA           3
## 7   24204 -3.484321e-04           2
## 8   24204  6.745363e-05           3
## 9   28102 -5.639098e-04           2
## 10  28102 -2.359882e-04           3
## 11  34104  2.594810e-04           2
## 12  34104 -2.747253e-05           3
## 13  43108 -4.433498e-04           2
## 14  43108 -1.098901e-04           3
## 15 103114 -3.937008e-04           2
## 16 103114 -4.123711e-04           3
## 17 114101 -3.448276e-04           2
## 18 114101  2.604167e-05           3
```

Alternate munging:

```
group_by(df, ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("DATE")), funs(as.Date(., "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>% 
  do(data_frame(date=as.Date(unlist(.[,5:7]), origin="1970-01-01"), # in the event you wanted to keep the data less awful and have one observation per row, this preserves the Date class
                reading=unlist(.[,2:4]))) %>% 
  do(data_frame(slope=diff(.$reading)/unclass(diff(.$date))))
```

Comment: The slope in this problem is decline across time for each observation and not for each visit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a "hacky" solution but if I understand your question correctly (some clarification may be needed), this should work in your case.  Note, this is somewhat specific to your case since the column pairs are expected to be in the order you specified.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

### Load Data
tdf <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = '
ID      FEV1_Date11 FEV1_Date12 FEV1_Date13  DATE11     DATE12     DATE13
18105   1.35        1.25        1.04         6/9/1990   8/16/1991  8/27/1993
18200   0.87        0.85        NA           9/12/1991  3/11/1993  NA
18303   0.79        NA          NA           4/23/1992  NA         NA
24204   4.05        3.95        3.99         6/8/1992   3/22/1993  11/5/1994
28102   1.19        1.04        0.96         10/31/1990 7/24/1991  6/27/1992
34104   1.03        1.16        1.15         7/25/1992  12/8/1993  12/7/1994
43108   0.92        0.83        0.79         6/23/1993  1/12/1994  1/11/1995
103114  2.43        2.28        2.16         6/5/1994   6/21/1995  4/7/1996
114101  0.73        0.59        0.6          6/25/1989  8/5/1990   8/24/1991') %>% tbl_df

#####################################
### Reshape the data by column pairs.
#####################################
### Function to reshape a single column pair
xform_data <- function(x) {
  df<-data.frame(tdf[,'ID'],
                 names(tdf)[x],
                 tdf[,names(tdf)[x]],
                 tdf[,names(tdf)[x+3]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(df) <- c('ID', 'DateKey', 'Val', 'Date'); df
}
### Create a new data frame with the data in a deep format (i.e. reshaped)
### 'lapply' is used to reshape each pair of columns (date and value).
### 'lapply' returns a list of data frames (on df per pair) and 'bind_rows'
### combines them into one data frame.
newdf <-
  bind_rows(lapply(2:4, function(x) {xform_data(x)})) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date, tz='utc'))

#####################################
### Calculate the slopes per ID
#####################################
slopedf <-
  newdf %>%
  arrange(DateKey, Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  do(slope = lm(Val ~ Date, data = .)$coefficients[[2]]) %>%
  mutate(slope = as.vector(slope)) %>%
  ungroup
slopedf
## # A tibble: 9 x 2
##       ID         slope
##    <int>         <dbl>
## 1  18105 -3.077620e-09
## 2  18200 -4.239588e-10
## 3  18303            NA
## 4  24204 -5.534095e-10
## 5  28102 -4.325210e-09
## 6  34104  1.690414e-09
## 7  43108 -2.490139e-09
## 8 103114 -4.645589e-09
## 9 114101 -1.924497e-09

##########################################
### Adding slope column to original data.
##########################################
> tdf %>% left_join(slopedf, by = 'ID')
## # A tibble: 9 x 8
##       ID FEV1_Date11 FEV1_Date12 FEV1_Date13     DATE11    DATE12    DATE13         slope
##    <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>
## 1  18105        1.35        1.25        1.04   6/9/1990 8/16/1991 8/27/1993 -3.077620e-09
## 2  18200        0.87        0.85          NA  9/12/1991 3/11/1993      <NA> -4.239588e-10
## 3  18303        0.79          NA          NA  4/23/1992      <NA>      <NA>            NA
## 4  24204        4.05        3.95        3.99   6/8/1992 3/22/1993 11/5/1994 -5.534095e-10
## 5  28102        1.19        1.04        0.96 10/31/1990 7/24/1991 6/27/1992 -4.325210e-09
## 6  34104        1.03        1.16        1.15  7/25/1992 12/8/1993 12/7/1994  1.690414e-09
## 7  43108        0.92        0.83        0.79  6/23/1993 1/12/1994 1/11/1995 -2.490139e-09
## 8 103114        2.43        2.28        2.16   6/5/1994 6/21/1995  4/7/1996 -4.645589e-09
## 9 114101        0.73        0.59        0.60  6/25/1989  8/5/1990 8/24/1991 -1.924497e-09
```

Comment: newdf <-
  bind_rows(lapply(2:4, function(x) {xform_data(x)})) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date, tz='utc'))

Comment: @SuchitKumbhare Is this meant to be a question ?

Comment: @SuchitKumbhare I am using the `lubridate` package which I added a line of code for (`library(lubridate)`).

Comment: Thank you..I am not able to understand the lapply function                                                                                                                ' newdf <- bind_rows(lapply(2:4, function(x) {xform_data(x)})) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date, tz='utc')) '   It results in fatal error. Could you please explain lapply and bind_rows?

Comment: @SuchitKumbhare The fatal error is likely because my data frame is called `tdf` and yours is not.  Also, you have to have both `dplyr` and `lubridate` loaded.

Comment: @SuchitKumbhare I added a little more explanation in the comments in the post.

Comment: what if there are NA is Val column, will it still work?

Comment: I guess this since Val has many NA's in data it shows    'Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases   '

Comment: @SuchitKumbhare In `lm` you can set `na.action`.  It seems the default is to omit `NA` and return `NA` when all values are `NA`.  So, you control this by setting `na.action` in `lm`.

Comment: @SuchitKumbhare If you have "corner" cases you are interested in handling or other use cases, please include them in the question or create a new question.  I don't know what you are trying to do with `lm.fit` (i.e. in your specific case).  It is best to give what your input is (which you did) and what output you expect (which is not quite there yet).  That will make it easier to address the various cases.

Comment: I slightly modified function by omiting NAs.. here is the code below                                                                                                          '          slopedf <-
           newdf %>% na.omit(newdf) %>%
           arrange(DateKey, Date) %>%
           group_by(ID) %>% 
           do(slope = lm(Val ~ Date, data = .)$coefficients[[2]]) %>%
            mutate(slope = as.vector(slope)) %>%
            ungroup